# selected checkboxes(dynamically created) values should be set to destination text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring, jsp

For destination text field, based on the input, the auto suggestion will be displayed as checkboxes. I can select one or more values and my requirement is to get these selected values on the controller side, Once I click on the search button. How can I achieve this for dynamic checkboxes, please provide any suggestions.

jquery:

```
$("#destinationName").autocomplete({
    source : function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/showDestinations",
            type: "POST",
            data: { term : request.term },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                $('.dest').html("");
                $.each(data, function(i, record) {
                    $('.dest').append("<br/><input class= 'src'     type='checkbox' id='chk-" + i + "' name='" + record + "' /> " + record);  
            });
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="searchForm" action="someAction/showStatistics" id="ems">
    <label>Destination</label>
    <input type="text" id="destinationName" name="destinationName" value="${someForm.destinationName}" class="field" />
    <div class="dest"></div>
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="search" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

    var dynamicCheckbox = [];

    $("#destinationName").autocomplete({
         source : function(request, response) {
         $.ajax({
              url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/showDestinations",
             type: "POST",
             data: { term : request.term },
             dataType: "json",
             success: function(data) {

                   $('.dest').html("");
                   $.each(data, function(i, record) {
                       $('.dest').append("<br/><input class= 'src' type='checkbox' id='chk-" + i + "' name='" + record + "' /> " + record);  
                   });
             };
          });
        }
    });

     $('.button').on('click', function (event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         $('.dest input:checked').each(function() {
              dynamicCheckbox.push($(this).attr('name'));
          });
          console.log(dynamicCheckbox);
      });
});
```

Here in `dynamicCheckbox` you will get the names of the checked checkboxes.
Hope that's what you need!

Comment: Thanks John. I will try and let you know by Monday, I unable to connect to the application through my local network (not related to question above).  Is there anyway that these dynamicCheckbox array can be sent along with the request, because I want these values on the controller, then pass on to DAO. Something like ,  request.getParameterValues("name");  Is it possible? please advise.

Comment: you mean you want to send data through the autocomplete ajax request. As of now the dynamicCheckbox will have value on submit button click.

Comment: you could `stringify` the `dynamicCheckbox` array and send as another item in object `data`.

Comment: Hi John, upon clicking the search button, I want the selected checkbox values to be sent.

Comment: Destination field will autosuggest values upon the input, whatever the values I selected, the statistics of these values are to be displayed upon the search button. Controller will take of the statistics part, however, all i want is getting the selected values on to the controller side, so that I can query with these values in DAO and get the results.

Comment: Then you could use another ajax call on the button click `stringify` the data and send to the controller.